# "how to read file and multiply one file value with another file index"

Tags: python-3.x

read a text and json files respectively and load the data in respective variables.
Then, use iterate a loop on them to calculate force accordingly, keeping the resultant value in a list, to be saved as a json in the end.

```
  import json


 acce = ''
   with open('accelration.txt', 'r') as js:
        for `line` in js:
        acce = line.split('  ')
print(acce)
['18,33,56,60,17,35,83,87,42,27,27,21,33,22,44,2']

mas = ''
 with open('mass.json', 'r') as js:
      for line in js:
      mas = line.split('  ')
print(mas)
 ['[1.8, 3.3, 5.6, 6.0, 1.7, 3.5, 8.3, 8.7, 4.2, 2.7, 0.27, 2.1, 3.3, 2.2, 0.44, 2.7]']

def force(a,m):
    for i in range(force):
    force.append(a*m)
print(force)
```

Comment: Please format the source code in your question

Comment: ['18,33,56,60,17,35,83,87,42,27,27,21,33,22,44,2']
['[1.8, 3.3, 5.6, 6.0, 1.7, 3.5, 8.3, 8.7, 4.2, 2.7, 0.27, 2.1, 3.3, 2.2, 0.44, 2.7]']
i have read the fies
now  i have to multiply them 1st value of one to 1st index of the 2nd

Comment: What's the *question*?

Comment: i have a text file and a json file i want to read them and  multiply them 1st vale to first index

Comment: What do you mean by first index? `F=ma` right so you just need to multiply the two lists?

Comment: Please show a sample of the contents of the JSON and txt file.

Comment: yes. u can say that f=ma

Comment: Print the contents of `acce` and `mas` and add the output to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step is to get a valid list of numbers for `acce` and `mas`.

Based on the contents that you posted, `accel` is a list containing a single string of comma separated values. So you first need to access that string with `accel[0]`, then get the list of values with `spli(,)` and convert each value to an `int`:

```
acce = ['18,33,56,60,17,35,83,87,42,27,27,21,33,22,44,2']

accel_list = [int(i) for i in acce[0].split(',')]
print(accel_list)
```

Output: `[18, 33, 56, 60, 17, 35, 83, 87, 42, 27, 27, 21, 33, 22, 44, 2]`

Next, `mas` is a list containing a string of comma separated values formatted as a list. So you can use `ast.literal_eval()` to evaluate that string as a list:

```
import ast
mas = ['[1.8, 3.3, 5.6, 6.0, 1.7, 3.5, 8.3, 8.7, 4.2, 2.7, 0.27, 2.1, 3.3, 2.2, 0.44, 2.7]']
mass_list = ast.literal_eval(mas[0])
print(mass_list)
```

Output: `[1.8, 3.3, 5.6, 6.0, 1.7, 3.5, 8.3, 8.7, 4.2, 2.7, 0.27, 2.1, 3.3, 2.2, 0.44, 2.7]`

Now that you have two valid lists (`accel_list` and `mass_list`), you can multiply them to get the force using list comprehension:

```
force = [a*m for a,m in zip(accel_list,mass_list)]
print(force)
```

Output: `[32.4, 108.89999999999999, 313.59999999999997, 360.0, 28.9, 122.5, 688.9000000000001, 756.9, 176.4, 72.9, 7.290000000000001, 44.1, 108.89999999999999, 48.400000000000006, 19.36, 5.4]`

If you want the result to be rounded to eg. 2 decimal places, you can do that inside the list comprehension as well:

```
force = [round(a*m,2) for a,m in zip(accel_list,mass_list)]
print(force)
```

Output: `[32.4, 108.9, 313.6, 360.0, 28.9, 122.5, 688.9, 756.9, 176.4, 72.9, 7.29, 44.1, 108.9, 48.4, 19.36, 5.4]`